# Addition-merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

What is the best way to add the contents of two dataframes, which have mostly equivalent indices:

df1:

```
    A   B   C

A   0   3   1

B   3   0   2

C   1   2   0
```

df2:

```
    A   B   C   D

A   0   1   1   0

B   1   0   3   2

C   1   3   0   0

D   0   2   0   0
```

df1 + df2 =

```
    A   B   C   D

A   0   4   2   0

B   4   0   5   2

C   2   5   0   0

D   0   2   0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just add:

```
In [625]: df1.add(df2,fill_value=0)
Out[625]: 
     A    B    C    D
A  0.0  4.0  2.0  0.0
B  4.0  0.0  5.0  2.0
C  2.0  5.0  0.0  0.0
D  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both the dataframes since concatenation (by default) happens by index.

```
# sample dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4]}, index=['a','c','e'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10,20], 'b':[11,22]}, index=['b','d'])

new_df= pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()

print(new_df)
    a   b
a   1   2
b   10  11
c   2   3
d   20  22
e   3   4
```